# Why is my config's `expandtab = true` overridden when most files are opened?

Tags: config, neovim

Neovim 0.8.0 with 34 plugins via packer. In a config file I have set `epandtab = true`. But a large majority of files opened for editing have `noexpandtab` set. This issue seems to be independent of filetype; e.g., of a couple dozen .lua files tested, only 3 had an `expandtab` result for `:set et?` and the rest a `noexpandtab` result. I used grep over all my config files and all the plugin repositories to find instances of `expandtab` and found many, but most were setting it to true and the rest were setting it to false in a non-applicable context.

I could write an autocmd to set it to true but I wonder what, if anything, that might break. What is a good way to find out what is the "culprit"?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The cause is the [`indent-o-matic`](https://github.com/Darazaki/indent-o-matic) plugin's design behavior -- not a bug. If it detects existing tab indentation, it sets `expandtab = false`. I adopted my config from someone else who uses tabs indentation. The minority of .lua files that have `expandtab` set per my global option setting have *no* indentation, so the plugin doesn't find tab indentation.

Comment: Great that you have found the culprit!

Answer (score 3):

This is an option precedence issue: you option is reset but other scripts in your runtime path.

In the file that has this issue, run command `:verbose set expandtab?`. It should print where `expandtab` is set lastly. You will see output like this:

```
expandtab
    Last set from ~\AppData\Local\nvim/core/options.vim line 50
```

To make sure your config takes precedence over all other configs, create filetype setting in the `after` directory under your nvim config directory. For example, if you would like to use `expandtab` for Python files, do the following:

- create file `~/.config/nvim/after/ftplugin/python.vim` or `~/.config/nvim/after/ftplugin/python.lua` (create necessary directories if they do not exist)
- add `set expandtab` to the above file if you use `python.vim` or add `vim.o.expandtab=true` if you use `python.lua`.

See also `:help after-directory`.

Comment: Thanks! I forgot to mention in the OP that the result with `verbose` is only `Last set from lua`. ... I will try the `after` suggestion. Do I need a file there for each filetype that I edit (lua, text, python, etc.)? As noted in my OP the issue seems independent of filetype -- it affects only _some_ lua files and only _some_ text files.

Comment: Yeah, for each filetype where `expandtab` is not right, you do the above for each separately, just like what I am doing [here](https://github.com/jdhao/nvim-config/tree/master/after/ftplugin). I think it will fix your issue.

Comment: In `~/.config/nvim/after/ftplugin/lua.lua` I have these two lines: `vim.o.expandtab = true` and `vim.notify('lua.lua loaded')`. When I start nvim with no argments, I get an nvim-tree file selector as I've configured. When from it I open one of the (majority of) lua files that previously returned `noexpandtab` from `:set et?` I then get the notify message, but the `:set et?` result is still `noexpandtab`. What might I be missing?

Comment: This is werid. What is the output of `verb set expandtab?`? It is hard to debug without knowing your env.

Comment: It's still just `Last set from Lua` -- not really informative.

Comment: can you comment out all content of `init.vim` jor `init.lua`. Restart nvim and open a lua file, what is the output of `set expandtab?`

Comment: (Was prompted to move this "extended discussion" to chat.) The output was `noexpandtab`. I also got the vim.notify message from `lua.lua`.

Comment: Sorry, I can not reproduce this. On my computer, the result is different. No idea now. Maybe you can use `FileType` autocmd to fix this for now.

Comment: If you need more information (e.g. file and line number) than `Last set from Lua`, use `nvim -V1`. See https://github.com/neovim/neovim/issues/23719

Answer (score 1):

`:verbose set expandtab?`

**Possible result 1**:

If it says come from a vimscript. follow the path, easy to fix.

**possible result 2**:

If it says come from a lua.

Check the folders up along to your root directory.

You may find a .editorconfig file. fix it. with

```
[*.py]
indent_style = space
indent_size = 4
```

**Reason:**

Newer neovim will respect .editorconfig over `expandtab` setting.

Code in share/nvim/runtime/lua/editorconfig.lua

```lua
function M.properties.indent_style(bufnr, val, opts)
  assert(val == 'tab' or val == 'space', 'indent_style must be either "tab" or "space"')
  vim.bo[bufnr].expandtab = val == 'space'
  if val == 'tab' and not opts.indent_size then
    vim.bo[bufnr].shiftwidth = 0
    vim.bo[bufnr].softtabstop = 0
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I was going absolutely nuts with this one using a .dotfiles repo I cloned from someone else and configured to my liking.

I kept trying to set up python to be handled with `expandtab`set, and tried loads of different ways of writing `after/ftplugin/python.lua`
including with a `print(I am loaded)` debug message that confirmed it was loading.

I did:

Open python file

```
:verbose set expandtab?
noexpandtab
        Last set from ~/.local/share/nvim/site/pack/packer/start/editorconfig-vim/plugin/editorconfig.vim line 394
:set expandtab
:verbose set expandtab?
  expandtab
```

Make and edit to the file and it got reset:

```
:verbose set expandtab?
noexpandtab
        Last set from ~/.local/share/nvim/site/pack/packer/start/editorconfig-vim/plugin/editorconfig.vim line 394
```

So after some facepalming I tracked down a `.editorconfig` file way up in my filesystem and to it I added

```
[*.py]
indent_style = space
indent_size = 4
trim_trailing_whitespace = true
insert_final_newline = true
```

which fixed my "inability" to persist `expandtab` in python files.

Posting here in case anyone else has same facepalm moment....

Comment: I have 45 instances of `.editorconfig` in my filesystem. They are associated with a variety of applications, including several in Packer-managed plugins.

Comment: The issue with mine was that they were in the direct path so in a path like 
/a/b/c/d/e there was on at c, and so it affected the behaviour of code opened in e